# ffmpeg overlay filter with enable parameter has a lag of two frames

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video

I want to overlay one video on another and want to do it very accurately (as I need to trim it later from that point) I am using a function to determine the value of enable parameter for the video which looks something like:

```
# dummy code
def get_visible():
 some_numeric_value = "between(t, y, z) + between(t, a, b)"
 return f"between(t, x, y) * if(gt(some_numeric_value,1), 0, 1)"
```

I use the returned value normally in my ffmpeg command like this:

```
ffmpeg \
-i /tmp/11906114-8505-45a0-a9ad-5a0ff96657f1.mp4 \
-loop 1 -i /tmp/55e06ba9-c032-432a-8618-a4a53ce6ed7e_scaled.png \
-loop 1 -i /tmp/553ba58a-fb9d-4cde-8087-f5cb7c181928_output.jpg \
-vcodec libvpx-vp9 -i /tmp/transparent_02099107-9e3e-4fe4-a678-2c76ac8d137b_final.webm \
-vcodec libvpx -i /tmp/a4c2c0c1-83fe-4741-8208-111dab7da860_output.webm \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=size=1920\\\\:1080[s0];\
[1:v]setpts=PTS+0/TB[s1];\
[s0][s1]overlay=enable=between(t\\,0\\, 3.5004583333333334):eof_action=pass:format=auto:x=0:y=0[s2];\
[2:v]setpts=PTS+3.5504583333333333/TB[s3];\
[s2][s3]overlay=enable=between(t\\,3.5504583333333333\\, 8.130458333333333):eof_action=pass:format=auto:x=0:y=0[s4];\
[3:v]tpad=start_duration=0:start_mode=clone:stop_duration=0:stop_mode=clone[s5];\
[s5]setpts=PTS+0/TB[s6];\
[s4][s6]overlay=enable=between(t\\,0\\, 3.5004583333333334):eof_action=repeat:format=auto:x=56:y=544[s7];\
[4:v]tpad=start_duration=0:start_mode=clone:stop_duration=0:stop_mode=clone[s8];\
[s8]setpts=PTS+3.5004583333333334/TB[s9];\
[s7][s9]overlay=enable=between(t\\, 3.5004583333333334\\, 8.200958333333332) * if(gt(1+between(t\\, 4.970458333333333\\, 6.810458333333333)+between(t\\, 7.120458333333334\\, 8.130458333333333)\\, 1)\\, 0\\, 1):eof_action=repeat:format=auto:x=-346:y=216[s10];\
[3:a]adelay=0|0[s11];[s11]apad=pad_dur=4.700499999999999[s12];\
[4:a]adelay=3500.4583333333335|3500.4583333333335[s13];\
[s13]apad=pad_dur=0.001[s14]\
;[s12][s14]amix=inputs=2[s15];\
[s15]volume=2[s16]" \
-map [s10] -map [s16] -acodec flac \
-crf 18 -g 1 -map_chapters -1 \
-vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline \
-shortest -strict -2 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -sample_fmt s16 \
/tmp/video.mp4
```

I want the overlays to be accurately placed without any lag of the aforementioned two frames that I am seeing. What else should I be doing to achieve this?

Comment: There are 4 overlays, which one is late? How are you determining timestamps of frames in your calculations?

Comment: I care about the webm overlays and they are late. Also, as you must have noticed I'm not just overlaying them I'm making them disappear and re-appear using the get_visibility fx, so there is the delay of two frames there as well.

Comment: @Gyan I'm not determining the timestamps of frames, how do I do that? 

I'm working under the assumping that if I overlay a video from x seconds to y seconds, and then do `ffmpeg -ss x -i input.mp4 -to y output.mp4` I would get the exact section where I have overlayed the video. Is that not correct? 

I have made every frame a keyframe to try and achieve this.

Comment: In `between(t\\,3.5504583333333333\\, 8.130458333333333)`, where are you getting the timestamps from?

Comment: I am calculating these timeframes using some custom logic to show/hide the webm videos.

Comment: I've found the issue in this, I had to do `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+{delay}`, I wasn't aligning all the streams to the start and somehow that was creating the issues.